# Docker Messing With IPTABLES?

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, route

I have a problem with docker

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external
> connectivity on endpoint containername
> (containerhash):
> (iptables failed: iptables --wait -t filter -A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -o
> docker0 -p tcp -d 172.17.0.4 --dport 28967 -j ACCEPT: iptables: No
> chain/target/match by that name.

In the boot log I see

> systemd-udevd[4611]: veth9c4b829: Failed to get link config: No such
> device

Have 4 network ports and it seems to do it at random for each. The idea is to have a separate IP from different /24 subnet for each container, but it looks like docker can't successfully generate outside world access for all of the containers at once. **Any advice, please?** Routing is done, ports are open and each IP from each network on different network port have ping. It is just docker messing with iptables in some weird way. Resetting firewall does not help.

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
ip6tables -t nat -F
ip6tables -t mangle -F
ip6tables -F
ip6tables -X
```

There is also IPv6 from different /64 network on each port.

Could post netplan (network config) and rc.local (adds routes at boot), if needed.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: Not really helping...